# Upgrade jars without changing build path in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, ant

Let's say I have a simple java project in Eclipse with a apache commons collections jar on the build path.

With every update rolled out to the jar, I have to manually update jar file in the build path since its name changes.

Is there a better way to upgrade to newer jars without having have to change the build path in Eclipse?

P.S: I'm not looking into package management tools like Maven. That's another topic. Just a plain and simple Eclipse or symbolic link style tip is all.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I was thinking of you seem to have suggested yourself in your last 6 words.

You could create 1 link with a name that is not expected to change and link it to your other file whose name does change. This is not much better though.

You could also rename the new jar each time you get a new one. For instance, if it is "coolLib-1_2.jar" to "coolLib-1_3.jar", just leave it in your path as "coolLib.jar"

All the answers are similar and require a small effort on your part. There is not really any way to get entirely around it if the new file's name is always expected to change. The best you can do is write a script or alias which handles it for you. Typing `coolLibUp` every once in a while is much easier than typing `pushd ${BUILD_PATH} ; rm coolLib.jar ; ln -s ${LIB_DIRECTORY}/coolLib-1_3.jar ; popd` all the time (or whatever other equivalent you use).

Or the windows equivalent: `%LIB_DIRECTORY%` instead of `${LIB_DIRECTORY}` and `mklink` instead of `ln -s`

Comment: Well I did try that and unfortunately, eclipse doesn't seem to understand symbolically linked jars.

Comment: @deluged.oblivion Not sure what the problem would be. Perhaps that should be your question instead (though that might be a superuser or server-fault question instead of SO). I use symbolic links with eclipse every day, both for libraries (C++ .so libraries though) and also the source files themselves are all actually symbolic links too.